# Summernote style is broken with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, summernote

Now I'm working on Laravel project, where added WYSIWYG editor - Summernote.

On the local summernote is working well and also confirmed summernote worked well on production too.

But I just noticed the style of summernote is not working on the prod.

In the meantime I didn't touch the summernote and tested it on local and prod with disable cache.

But still get working on the local and not working on the prod.

Here is the code.

JS

```
$('.summernote').summernote();
```

Blade

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Additional Notes</label>
     <textarea rows="15" class="form-control summernote" name="notes"
               value="{{$license[0]['notes']}}">{{$license[0]['notes']}}
     </textarea>
</div>
```

Also attached the screenshot of production.

[image: Summernote style is broken]

If you have any solution, please help me.

Regards.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Summernote, but I'm guessing it's missing some of the icons for the buttons due to a change in URL. Check your Network tab of your Developer Console, as well as the Console tab, to see if there's any hints there.

Comment: Read the docs https://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation